# Numpy Hermitian Matrix class

Tags: performance, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, multiplication

Are you aware of something like a hermitian matrix class in numpy? I'd like to optimize matrix calculations like

B = U * A * U.H

, where A (and thus, B) are hermitian. Without specification, all matrix elements of B are calculated. In fact, it should be able to save a factor of about 2 here. Do I miss something?

The method I need should take take the upper/lower triangle of A, the full matrix of U and return the upper/lower triangle of B.

Comment: what problem are you facing doing this

Comment: Well, in the end I need the triangular matrix B[numpy.triu_indices(dim),0]. However, calculating (U*A*U.H)[numpy.triu_indices(dim)], I do first calculate all elements of (U*A*U.H) and then pick the upper triangle. Wouldnt it be more reasonable to calculate the upper triangle only?

Comment: Hermitian function defined here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#customizing-your-environment

Comment: Sorry, I think i was not clear enough. I do not need a function that calculates the hermitian of a matrix. I'd like to exploit the symmetry of self-adjoint matrices (or symmetric matrices for real numbers) in order to achive a more efficient calculation of products / transformations. In more easy words: Calculate the upper triangle of B without calculating the lower triangle first. I'd like to avoid python loops.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there exists a method for your specific problem, but with a little thought you might be able to build an algorithm from the low-level BLAS routines that are wrapped in SciPy. For example, `dgemm`, `dsymm`, and `dtrmm` do general, symmetric, and triangular matrix products respectively. Here's an example of using them:

```
from scipy.linalg.blas import dgemm, dsymm, dtrmm

A = np.random.rand(10, 10)
B = np.random.rand(10, 10)
S = np.dot(A, A.T)  # symmetric matrix
T = np.triu(S)  # upper triangular matrix

# normal matrix-matrix product
assert np.allclose(dgemm(1, A, B), np.dot(A, B))

# symmetric mat-mat product using only upper-triangle
assert np.allclose(dsymm(1, T, B), np.dot(S, B))

# upper-triangular mat-mat product
assert np.allclose(dtrmm(1, T, B), np.dot(T, B))
```

There are many other low-level BLAS routines available; I find [the NETLIB page](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) to be a good resource to learn what they do. You may be able to cleverly use some combination of the available routines to efficiently solve the problem you have in mind.

Edit: it looks like there are LAPACK routines that quickly compute exactly what you want: [dsytrd](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dsytrd.f.html) or [zhetrd](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zhetrd.f.html), but unfortunately these don't appear to be wrapped directly in [`scipy.linalg.lapack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.lapack.html), though scipy does provide [cython wrappers](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.cython_lapack.html) for them. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I needed tridiagonal reduction of a symmetric/Hermitian matrix `A`,

```
T = Q^H * A * Q
```

– presumably OP's underlying problem – and I've just submitted [a pull request to SciPy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7780) for properly interfacing LAPACK's [`{s,d}sytrd`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dsytrd.f.html) (for real symmetric matrices) and [`{c,z}hetrd`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/zhetrd.f.html) (for Hermitian matrices). All routines use either only the upper or the lower triangular part of the matrix.

Once this has been merged, it can be used like

```
import numpy as np

n = 3
A = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=dtype)
A[np.triu_indices_from(A)] = np.arange(1, 2*n+1, dtype=dtype)

# query lwork -- optional
lwork, info = sytrd_lwork(n)
assert info == 0

data, d, e, tau, info = sytrd(A, lwork=lwork)
assert info == 0
```

The vectors `d` and `e` now contain the main diagonal and the upper and lower diagonal, respectively.